# Push to Git+SSH from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

We have a Jenkins pipline that retrieves a repository using an SSH key (secret text) and the initial clone works fine.

But in this pipeline I need to add the results back to the repository, and that's why we have

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'secretTextId', keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
    sh "git checkout master"    // 'Cause Jenkins uses a detached head for building
    sh 'git add .'
    sh '''git commit -m "Update from `date +"%Y-%m-%d"`"'''
    sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $KEY_FILE" git push'
}
```

But that always fails with

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I expected that, by using the credentials and saving it as a text file, and forcing Git to use the file for the SSH, everything would work. But, so far, it looks like either Jenkins is not actually saving the file, saving it wrong or, for some reason, Git is not using this file during `git push`.